# Post Confirmation ConfirmForgotPassword lambda execution returns InvalidLambdaResponseException - Unrecognizable lambda output

Tags: authentication, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have spent a bunch of hours to solve this issue, all related SO answers seem to be outdated or irrelevant.

State:

- Amplify.js "^4.3.10" with code

  ```
       Auth.forgotPasswordSubmit(email, confirmationCode, password)
       .then(_ => this.notification.success("Confirmation OK"))
       .catch(err => console.log(err));
  ```
- Lambda on Node.js 14
- Cognito trigger "Post confirmation"

Lambda function code:

```
'use strict';

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    if (event.triggerSource === "PostConfirmation_ConfirmForgotPassword") {
      const postConfirmEmail = () => `<html><body>HERE IS MY TEMPLATE</body></html>`;
    
      event.response = {
          emailSubject: "Reset Password Notification",
          emailMessage: postConfirmEmail()
      };
      
      callback(null, event);
    } 
};
```

As result, I am getting
**InvalidLambdaResponseException: Unrecognizable lambda output (Error 400)**

The thing is that password is really updating as expected, but e-mail confirmation is NOT sent and error remains.

TIP: User is CONFIRMED. Tried also with "context.done(null, event);" / "return event;" but response is always with the same error.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using an async handler with the callback. It's either one or the other.

Simply return `event` without calling the callback or don't make your function async.

Additionally, Cognito will not send confirmation emails, you will have to implement this functionality yourself.